# Serving static content in Django results in 404 for CSS file

Tags: python, django, static-files

So I've carefully read this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/. I have done the following:

**In urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       ('^SearchFoos$', searchForFoos),
                       ('^Foo/(\d+)$', showFoo),
                       (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/home/david/workspace/fooapp/fooapp/static'}),
)
```

I have a file called `site.css` at the location `/home/david/workspace/fooapp/fooapp/static/css`.

**In the template**

My template contains the following link:

```
<link href="/static/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Yet when I load the page using the runserver, Firefox gives me a 404 for the CSS file. It's trying to get the file from the location `http://localhost:8000/static/css/site.css`, which is what I would have expected.

I've stared at this and stared at it and can't see the problem. Can anyone help (I'm totally new to python and django).

Comment: Are you sure you are using Django 1.2? it is pretty old stuff

Comment: `django.VERSION` gives me `(1, 4, 1, 'final', 0)`.

Comment: so guess you should have been reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Comment: I don't see any downvotes - although it's a long time using it, I'm fairly sure Django has a static allowed for use in templates (my personal opinion though is just serve static through load balanced nginx front ends)

Comment: looks like a perfectly good question to me. +1

Comment: I think the downvoter relented. Thanks for your help guys. @fsw, if you want to provide an answer with your link, I'll mark you right.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that other people had submitted answers...

Comment: I am happy I was able to help. I don't care about glory and fame.

Comment: what a marvellous first experience of the django community... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [django 1.4 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) on serving static files in development. If you're not using the built in django server you'll need to add this to your urls.py file. making sure that your STATIC_DIRS and STATIC_URL settings are properly configured.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

As noted in the docs, you'll need to make sure `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py.

If you're using the built in django server you just need to put your static files in a directory called static at the top level of your app and it will [just work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#basic-usage).

Comment: J4I: You're not forced to use the `staticfiles_urlpatterns` - it still works the "old way"

Comment: As init3 implies - I was suggesting replacing your shabby, old, outdated, static url entry with my shinny new code.

Comment: And whilst you might not be 'forced' to use the shinny new method, it's fair to say that the old method is 'bad' and if you use it a fairy will probably die.

Comment: I just had to make a change to `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py` and a jazz guitar playing pisky appeared and took all my troubles away.

Comment: Sorry - what I mean is - I didn't need *any* URL entry at all - it appears in 1.4, the runserver will serve static content by default, using the `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_URL` settings respectively to look for static files and provide a base URL for them.

Comment: Although am I right in thinking that if you allow django to serve static files in production than another fairy dies? Is the idea that you configure the webserver itself to serve the static content and django never knows anything about it? ... just trying to work this stuff out.

Comment: Yes, lots of fairy's. Use `python manage.py collectstatic` to move all static files to STATIC_ROOT and have your webserver serve them at STATIC_URL.

Comment: Ah! Ding! [sound of a penny dropping]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
(r'static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/home/david/workspace/fooapp/fooapp/static'}),
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As @fsw pointed out, the whole means of enabling serving static content changed between version 1.2 and 1.4.